# Change button text (show / hide/ show) on click in jquery toggle

Tags: jquery, button, toggle

I am working on this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/cED6c/7/
I want to make the button text change on click and I tried using the following code:

```
<input type="button" class="reveal" onClick="this.value=this.value=='Show Answer'?'Hide Answer':'Show Answer'" value="Show Answer">
```

However, it does not work. How should I implement this? Any help would be great.

Comment: Why are you showing an `input` in your question, but using `button` elements in your linked demo?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add this code:

```
if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Show Answer') {
    $(this).text('Hide Answer');
} else {
    $(this).text('Show Answer');        
}
```

You can see it at work:

http://jsfiddle.net/cED6c/13/

I add the trim function cause in the html you got space after the Show Answer.

Comment: should I change this as well $("a[href='" + window.location.hash + "']").parent(".answerbutton").click();         not working in wordpress but it is fine in jsfiddle.

Comment: In the jsfiddle attached you don't have any a tag. What does it suppose to do?

Comment: OK, you want the question to be open by the href and location?

Comment: it supposed to be window.location.href (for all url) or window.location.href.hash (only for the hash)

Comment: use: $(this).parent().next('.toggle_container').slideToggle("fast");

Comment: Because in your site you got <p></p> wrapping the <button></button>

Answer (score 6):

Very easy to change the text using jQuery.

Working example here. http://jsfiddle.net/vp7Y7/

```
$('.reveal').click(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === 'Show Answer') {
         $(this).text('This is NEW TEXT!!! It Worked!');
    }
    else {
        $(this).text('Show Answer');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it really worked, but when I click it again, it does not revert to Show answer text.

Comment: Thanks, still I am unable to get it :( sorry for being naive. Please see this fiddle, only third button is working not the first two ones.http://jsfiddle.net/cED6c/10/

Answer (score 1):

something easy like this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.edit').click(function () {
        var txt = $(this).text();
        txt = (txt !='cancel') ? 'cancel' : 'edit';
        $(this).text(txt);
        $('.editForm').toggle(300);
     });
});
```