# HTML - Button is cancelled only after second click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple code: I want to cancel a button after it's clicked to display something else. I tried this way

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="button" value="New game" onclick="newGame()" />
</div>
```

js:

```
function newGame() {
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.removeChild(container.childNodes[0]);
}
```

What happens is the button gets cancelled only if I click it two times. Where did I get wrong?
I'm sorry if this is a repost, I tried to check but didn't find a quetion identical to mine

Comment: It may help, look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214590/change-button-text-show-hide-show-on-click-in-jquery-toggle Thank you

Comment: please accept an answer which helped you to solve your problem. It may helps others too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove `\n` (i.e *new line*) your code will work

try like this

```js
function newGame() {
var container = document.getElementById("container");
debugger;
container.removeChild(container.childNodes[0]);
}
```

```html
<div id="container"><input type="button" value="New game" onclick="newGame()" /></div>
```

The reason why your code is not working is, when you hit `enter` after `div`, HTML DOM will automatically creates one dummy text node as it's child. hence your `input` node became the **second child** for your `container`.

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mr_7/a25pLbsw/1/)**

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if your code is going to remove the button once you click on it. Is this correct, or are we not looking at the full markup?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want, but the button gets removed on the second click...the code goes on creating a table, so if I click the button two times, it's a problem because i get two tables

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function newGame() {
    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    // change 0 to 1
    container.removeChild(container.childNodes[1]);
}
```

`container.childNodes[0]` is a text Node, in which the text is `Newline`

Answer (score 0):

I gave id to the button and removed it using id.
In your case it is not removing in first time because container.childNodes[0] in first time is not a button. Try your self using console.log in your function.

```js
function newGame() {
   var container = document.getElementById("container");
    var d_nested = document.getElementById("button_1");
    var throwawayNode = container.removeChild(d_nested);
    //container.innerHTML='';
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <input id="button_1" type="button" value="New game" onclick="newGame()" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
<div id="container">
<input type="button" value="New game" onclick="document.getElementById('container').removeChild(this);" />
```

No separate JS file needed.